# LetsEncrypt not verifying via Kubernetes ingress and loadbalancer in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

LetsEncrypt not verifying via Kubernetes ingress and loadbalancer in AWS EKS

ClientIssuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: my@email.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class:  nginx
```

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - echo0.site.com
    secretName: echo-tls
  rules:
    - host: echo0.site.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: echo0
            servicePort: 80
```

Events

```
12m         Normal    IssuerNotReady         certificaterequest/echo-tls-3171246787   Referenced issuer does not have a Ready status condition
12m         Normal    GeneratedKey           certificate/echo-tls                     Generated a new private key
12m         Normal    Requested              certificate/echo-tls                     Created new CertificateRequest resource "echo-tls-3171246787"
4m29s       Warning   ErrVerifyACMEAccount   clusterissuer/letsencrypt-staging        Failed to verify ACME account: context deadline exceeded
4m29s       Warning   ErrInitIssuer          clusterissuer/letsencrypt-staging        Error initializing issuer: context deadline exceeded
```

kubectl describe certificate

```
Name:         echo-tls
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha3
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-04-04T23:57:22Z
  Generation:          1
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  echo-ingress
    UID:                   1018290f-d7bc-4f7c-9590-b8924b61c111
  Resource Version:        425968
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/default/certificates/echo-tls
  UID:                     0775f965-22dc-4053-a6c2-a87b46b3967c
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    echo0.site.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  echo-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-04-04T23:57:22Z
    Message:               Waiting for CertificateRequest "echo-tls-3171246787" to complete
    Reason:                InProgress
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age   From          Message
  ----    ------        ----  ----          -------
  Normal  GeneratedKey  18m   cert-manager  Generated a new private key
  Normal  Requested     18m   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "echo-tls-3171246787"
```

Been going at this for a few days now. I have tried with different domains, but end up with same results. Am I missing anything here/steps. It is based off of this tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `context deadline exceeded` sounds like the `cert-manager` pod was not able to reach the ACME api -- does your cluster have weird outbound firewalls, and/or does it have a NAT or Internet Gateway attached to the subnets? Turning up the `cert-manager` verbosity may help, too

Comment: That was it. Went ahead to rebuilt the cluster, made sure the nodes/pods had outbound access. All working now.

Comment: @mdaniel, What you think about post an answer here to help other in community? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually with golang applications the error `context deadline exceeded` means the connection timed out. That sounds like the `cert-manager` pod was not able to reach the ACME API, which can happen if your cluster has an outbound firewalls, and/or does not have a NAT or Internet Gateway attached to the subnets

Comment: this answer does not seem to take other cluster possibilities into account

Comment: @RahulBali Thank you for your contribution; this answer was posted by request and didn't claim to be the only thing possibly wrong -- that would be a very long list

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am currently stuck at this place. How do I check if my connectivity is fine or is this something else ? a heads up would be great. I am using bare metal k8s cluster, with nginx ingress.

Comment: You would ask your own question, instead of trying to have an entire debugging session in the comments of an existing answer, and if your question is "why does my networking not work," you'll want to ask those questions over on https://ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

This might be worthwhile to look at. I was facing similar issue.

Change `LoadBalancer` in `ingress-nginx` service.

Add/Change `externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster`.

Reason being, pod with the certificate-issuer wound up on a different node than the load balancer did, so it couldn’t talk to itself through the ingress.

Below is complete block taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.26.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  #CHANGE/ADD THIS
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https

---
```